# How to check if the effect from independent variable is changing over time?

Tags: regression, least-squares, econometrics, interaction, panel-data

I have panel data and want to find out whether the effect of key independent variable is changing over time.

At first, I intended to run OLS for each year separately, then compare coefficients.

But then I started to have doubts. Maybe there is a better strategy?

Comment: Wht do you mean by pooled OLS?

Comment: usual OLS, but on the whole sample

Comment: So what do you do with the cross-section? Do you intend to compute the mean values and then fit the model using these mean values?

Comment: It looks like my post is confusing you, isn't it? "I want to find out whether the effect of key independent variable is changing over time". Or are you asking me about something else?

Comment: I re-wrote my post. Hope this clears confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the estimates at each year separately is a reasonable descriptive strategy for what you're doing. If you're looking for a formal test, you could use a varying coefficient regression model.

Briefly, the varying coefficient model extends the standard regression model:

$$ y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + \epsilon_i $$

to allow the coefficient (say, the slope) to be a function of time:

$$ y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1(t) x_i + \epsilon_i $$

In general, there are not parametric specifications on the functional form of $\beta_1(t)$, but the practicality of a nonparametric estimate depends on how much data you have and the level of variability in $t$.  When you assume a linearly varying coefficient, i.e. $\beta_1(t) = \beta t$, this is equivalent to a linear interaction by time. You can test the null hypothesis $\beta_1(t) = c$ (i.e. a non-varying coefficient) by comparing the two models above. The are nested, so the likelihood ratio test is applicable.

These models were first introduced as a special case of generalized additive models in

Hastie, T.; R. Tibshirani (1993). "Varying-Coefficient Models". Journal of the Royal Statistical Society, Series B. 55: 757–796.

If you use `R`, you can fit varying coefficient models using `mgcv`, e.g. `gam(y~s(x,by=z))` estimates how the coefficient for $z$ varies as a function of $x$. See the help file for more info.

Comment: Thank you! You wrote that " this is equivalent to a linear interaction by time". If I am ok with assumption of linearly varying coefficient, do I understand you correctly, that I could just add interaction and run OLS?

Comment: @Michael, yes that would work

Comment: An alternate to a linearly varying coefficient could be or to use a spline, or using fused lasso. Search this site.