# Creating a plot for twoway fixed effects regression on how estimator changes over time

Tags: r, data-visualization, panel-data, regression-coefficients, fixed-effects-model

I am running a twoways (individual and time) fixed effects within model.

**Is there an econometrically sensible way to plot how the within effect of the independent variable changes over time?**

Or would this be senseless? The reason I want to do this is that the within effect dramatically changes/flips after some important change at time t in the data/my object of study.

I am giving an easy example in `R` using `plm` and plotting with `ggplot2` for better intuition. But my question is about the econometrics/statistics side of this.

```
library(plm)
library(tidyverse)

# Create some random data
set.seed(1) 
x=rnorm(100); fe=rep(rnorm(10),each=10); id=rep(1:10,each=10); ti=rep(1:10,10); e=rnorm(100)
y=x+fe+e
b=rnorm(100)

data=data.frame(y,x,id,ti)

# Run Twoway FE Regressions for 
plotframe <- NULL
for(n in c(2:10)){

  reg=plm(y~x,model="within",index=c("id","ti"), effect = "twoways", 
          data = filter(data, ti <= n ))

  reg <- broom::tidy(reg, conf.int = TRUE)

  estim <- reg$estimate
  sterr <- reg$std.error
  conf.low <- reg$conf.low
  conf.high <- reg$conf.high

  out <- data.frame(n, estim, sterr, conf.low, conf.high)

  plotframe <- rbind(plotframe, out)

}

# Plot it
ggplot(data = plotframe, aes(x=n, y=estim))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=conf.low,ymax=conf.high),alpha=0.3)+
  xlab("Time")+ylab("Estimator")
```

Comment: Just a thought! It may be right or wrong. You are computing the within effect by filtering the time period. The estimates are not varying over time. Instead, you're extending the time difference each time. If you have the filter as "filter(data, ti>=n-1, ti <=n)", we could say that the estimates are varying over time. In you case, it is better to have the bar plot instead of time series plot.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/269743/how-to-check-if-the-effect-from-independent-variable-is-changing-over-time or https://rdrr.io/cran/tvReg/man/tvPLM.html could help